# No PokeStops, Gyms, or nearby Pokemon showing up

Tags: pokemon-go

I've had the game for awhile (lvl 19) and I work in a state park in federal way Washington that has always had 2 gyms and 3 pokestops. Just recently I opened the app to see there were no stops or gyms anywhere nearby and this park is like in the middle of Tacoma so there are plenty.
 I reopened the app and they were back but now they are not showing up even after reopening app many times and redownloading app. 
I know niantic didn't just remove the 30+ stops and gyms around me which is what many threads seem to deem the case so it must be a glitch right?
Any help in resolving this issue would be awesome.. Can't catch Pokemon with potions unfortunately.

Comment: Could be server trouble. That happens pretty frequently for me, and I just have to wait a while for the servers to stabilize and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a softban. It should last for some hours (about 3 or so). Maybe they falsely detected you cheating because you changed your position to fast or you used the same account in different apps / on different devices at the same time.
After some time of maybe 3 hours, everything should be as it was.

You could try to log out of the app and log back in. If there is no problem loading, it should be a softban.

**edit**:
Today I found an article written by a [german site](http://www.spieletipps.de/n_37168/) which points out that this is an in-game error and there is to now no explanation of this effect.